# Replacing a Stream with a String in a C# program

Tags: c#, stream

Currently, I have a program that reads a file and uses an XMLTextWriter to write an XML file to disk. Shortly afterward, I read the file and parse it.

I am trying to put these two programs together. I want to get rid of the writing to file step. The XMLTextWriter needs a file path or a Stream when it is constructed. Is there a way to make a Stream that will create a string with the output instead of writing it to a file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XmlTextWriter also has a constructor that can take a TextWriter, so you can simply use a StringWriter:

```
string xml;
using (StringWriter str = new StringWriter()) {
  using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(str)) {
    // write the XML
  }
  xml = str.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to use a `MemoryStream`:

```
// To give code something to read
Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
CallRealCode(memoryStream);


// To give code something to write:
Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
CallRealCode(memoryStream);
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

(Adjust to an appropriate encoding, of course.)

Alternatively, if you can provide your code with a `TextWriter` instead of a `Stream`, you could use a `StringWriter`. One point to note is that by default, `StringWriter` will advertise itself as wanting to use UTF-16. You can override this behaviour with a subclass, like this:

```
public sealed class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.UTF8; } }
}
```

(Obviously you could do this in a more flexible way, too...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx).